# tolua++: Transfer pointer ownership to lua gc

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api, tolua++

Is there a way to return objects allocated on the the heap to lua without 'caching' references to them?

Consider the following:

```
class foo
{
    char const* bar() const
    {
        char* s = malloc(...);
        ...
        return s; // << Leak. How to transfer the ownership of 's' to lua?
    }
};
```

If I return a string to allocated memory i have to delete it.
Is there a way to transfer the ownership to lua?

Or is it even possible to get the `lua_state*` to implement string returning by myself using `lua_pushstring(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By declaring a parameter 'lua_Sate* state' tolua++ will pass the Lua-State to the function.

With a return type of type 'lua_Object' you can return the stack-index to a lua object.

PKG

```
lua_Object MyFunctionReturningATable(lua_State* s);
```

CPP

```
lua_Object MyFunctionReturningATable(lua_State* s)
{
    lua_newtable(s);

    ...

    return lua_gettop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your string into Lua with the [lua_pushstring](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pushstring) function and free it afterwards:

> Pushes the zero-terminated string pointed to by s onto the stack. Lua makes (or reuses) an internal copy of the given string, so the **memory at s can be freed or reused immediately after the function returns**. The string cannot contain embedded zeros; it is assumed to end at the first zero.

If you really want ownership to be transfered, consider wrapping your string into appropriate [object](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_newuserdata) with its own metatable and implementing `__gc` function.

Comment: The problem with `push_string` is that i dont have access to the `lua_state` in my c++ functions (?)